# Какая защита нужна о такой проблемы с исходящими запросами?

Tags: php, .htaccess

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается сайт часто отключают на VPs сервер, потому что идет огромная нагрузка по исходящим запросам, можно ли как то надежно защититься от этого?

Comment: Три-четыре запроса в секунду - это очень-очень маленькая нагрузка, и vps за такое отключать не будут. Если у вас от этого проблемы - у вас чудовищно неоптимизированный сайт и его надо переделывать

Comment: откуда у вас вообще исходящие запросы?

Comment: на сервере 10 сайтов и у всех такие проблемы нашел вирусные файлы удалил но хочу защититься максимально от таких ситуации как сделать?

Comment: Если сайты заражены вирусами, то их нужно переустанавливать с нуля, затем разбираться, как вирусы вообще проникли, и исправлять ту брешь, через которую проникли.

Comment: 1) В вашем логе нет исходящих запросов.
2) VPS по нагрузке отключать не должны, только ограничивать в ресурсах.
3) Ошибки в логах не указывают на повышеную нагрузку, только на ошибки

Comment: @Coder "*первая ссылка как раз Ваш случай*" - совет защищаться от DDoS, когда сайт забит вирусами, выглядит крайне сомнительно

Comment: @Coder чудовищно вредные советы, написанные без понимания механизмов атак, работающие чисто на везении и при этом ухудшающие удобство пользования сайтом.

Comment: @andreymal - Ok)